# Why is an ISB needed after WFI in Cortex-M FreeRTOS?

Tags: freertos, cortex-m

I see the following lines in the Cortex-M port of FreeRTOS when using the tickless idle functionality that relies on the WFI instruction

```
__asm volatile( "dsb" );
__asm volatile( "wfi" );
__asm volatile( "isb" );
```

See https://github.com/cjlano/freertos/blob/V9.0.0/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM3/port.c#L530

I see that per the ARM Cortex-M Programming Guide to Memory Barrier Instructions document: "A DSB should be used to ensure that there are no outstanding memory transactions prior to executing the WFI or WFE instruction."

But I am curious about why the ISB is necessary here? Perhaps this ensures that the interrupt which awoke the chip from WFI executes immediately before any further instructions that might be sitting in the pipeline? That's my best guess but would like to hear any other thoughts or confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the intention of the ISB is to ensure that the wfi instruction is executed "in order" and no instructions after it are executed until it wakes up. That said, I do not think that it is required according the the ARM documentation. I suspect it is belt and braces approach.

Comment: It might also be a workaround, e.g. for a pipeline bug in a specific core implementation.

Comment: Here's corroboration of the ISB being a "belt and braces approach"___
From "ARM Cortex™-M Programming Guide to Memory Barrier Instructions" Application Note 321.___
The section, "4.14 Entering sleep modes" does not mention using ISB after WFI___
The whole doc does not appear to mention using ISB after WFI.

Answer (score 0):

ISB is added after WFI because programmer wants to insure that WFI should executes before any instruction following WFI.
ARM also have A-Class cores which supports out of order execution. If we run above code by removing ISB on out of order cores then instruction following WFI may execute before WFI.

Answer (score 0):

ISB instruction will cause the pipelined to be flushed at some point, one use case for it is to force the ordering of instructions execution, based on that if we have one instruction after WFI we may want that WFI get executed really before the next instruction specially that for more sophisticated arm processor with support of out-of-order execution model or superscalar one we may get the instruction after WFI get fetched and feeded to the processor pipeline already, one workaround here is to use ISB to flush the pipeline causing the WFI to be executed which trigger the CPU to go to sleep mode and we guarantee that next instruction to not get executed

Answer (score -1):

ISB instruction flushes the pipeline and ensures that all
previous instructions are completed before executing new instructions.

From the ARM cortex-M3 guide.

> The DSB and ISB instructions can be important for self-modifying code. For example, if a program
>   changes its own program code, the next executed instruction should be based on the updated program.
>   However, since the processor is pipelined, the modified instruction location might have already been
>   fetched. Using DSB and then ISB can ensure that the modified program code is fetched again.
>   Architecturally, the ISB instruction should be used after updating the value of the CONTROL register. In the Cortex-M3 processor, this is not strictly required. But if you want to make sure your application is portable, you should ensure an ISB instruction is used after updating to CONTROL register.

Comment: The docs you quote mention only self-modifying code, which is not applicable to FreeRTOS, and the CONTROL register which also not applicable in the case to FreeRTOS. So your answer doesn't explain how ISB relates to WFI.